# Redis Sentinel master not downgraded to slave immediately

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I have an architecture with three Redis instances (one master and two slaves) and three Sentinel instances. In front of it there is a HaProxy. All works well until the master Redis instance goes down. The new master is properly chosen by Sentinel. However, the old master (which is now down) is not reconfigured to be a slave. As a result, when that instance is up again I have two masters for a short period of time (about 11 seconds). After that time that instance which was brought up is properly downgraded to slave.

Shouldn't it work that way, that when the master goes down it is downgraded to slave straight away? Having that, when it was up again, it would be slave immediately. I know that (since Redis 2.8?) there is that CONFIG REWRITE functionality so the config cannot be modified when the Redis instance is down.

Having two masters for some time is a problem for me because the HaProxy for that short period of time instead of sending requests to one master Redis, it does the load balancing between those two masters.

Is there any way to downgrade the failed master to slave immediately?

Obviously, I changed the Sentinel timeouts.

Here are some logs from Sentinel and Redis instances after the master goes down:

Sentinel

```
81358:X 23 Jan 22:12:03.088 # +sdown master redis-ha 127.0.0.1                       63797.0.0.1 26381 @ redis-ha 127.0.0.1 6379
81358:X 23 Jan 22:12:03.149 # +new-epoch 1
81358:X 23 Jan 22:12:03.149 # +vote-for-leader 6b5b5882443a1d738ab6849ecf4bc6b9b32ec142 1
81358:X 23 Jan 22:12:03.174 # +odown master redis-ha 127.0.0.1 6379 #quorum 3/2
81358:X 23 Jan 22:12:03.174 # Next failover delay: I will not start a failover before Sat Jan 23 22:12:09 2016
81358:X 23 Jan 22:12:04.265 # +config-update-from sentinel 127.0.0.1:26381 127.0.0.1 26381 @ redis-ha 127.0.0.1 6379
81358:X 23 Jan 22:12:04.265 # +switch-master redis-ha 127.0.0.1 6379 127.0.0.1 6381
81358:X 23 Jan 22:12:04.266 * +slave slave 127.0.0.1:6380 127.0.0.1 6380 @ redis-ha 127.0.0.1 6381
81358:X 23 Jan 22:12:04.266 * +slave slave 127.0.0.1:6379 127.0.0.1 6379 @ redis-ha 127.0.0.1 6381
81358:X 23 Jan 22:12:06.297 # +sdown slave 127.0.0.1:6379 127.0.0.1 6379 @ redis-ha 127.0.0.1 6381
```

Redis

```
81354:S 23 Jan 22:12:03.341 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
81354:S 23 Jan 22:12:03.341 # Error condition on socket for SYNC: Connection refused
81354:S 23 Jan 22:12:04.265 * Discarding previously cached master state.
81354:S 23 Jan 22:12:04.265 * SLAVE OF 127.0.0.1:6381 enabled (user request from 'id=7 addr=127.0.0.1:57784 fd=10 name=sentinel-6b5b5882-cmd age=425 idle=0 flags=x db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=3 qbuf=14 qbuf-free=32754 obl=36 oll=0 omem=0 events=rw cmd=exec')
81354:S 23 Jan 22:12:04.265 # CONFIG REWRITE executed with success.
81354:S 23 Jan 22:12:04.371 * Connecting to MASTER 127.0.0.1:6381
81354:S 23 Jan 22:12:04.371 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
81354:S 23 Jan 22:12:04.371 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
81354:S 23 Jan 22:12:04.371 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
81354:S 23 Jan 22:12:04.371 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)
81354:S 23 Jan 22:12:04.372 * Full resync from master: 07b3c8f64bbb9076d7e97799a53b8b290ecf470b:1
81354:S 23 Jan 22:12:04.467 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: receiving 860 bytes from master
81354:S 23 Jan 22:12:04.467 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Flushing old data
81354:S 23 Jan 22:12:04.467 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Loading DB in memory
81354:S 23 Jan 22:12:04.467 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Finished with success
```